# Sorting multiple data from swift firebase in alphabetical order in tableview cell

Tags: swift, sorting, uitableview

I'm doing a dictionary application. firebase also has a dictionary title and description. I pull this data into x code. I show the title in the tableview cell. but I could not sort by alphabetical order, I will just sort the fizik.baslik. 
I'm working in swift 4, xcode 11

```
class FizikSozluk{
var fizik_id : String?
var baslik :String?
var aciklama:String?
var animasyonAdi:String?
```

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var seachbar: UISearchBar!
var fizikListe = [FizikSozluk]()


var ref : DatabaseReference!

extension ViewController2 : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    fizikListe.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let fizik = fizikListe[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sozluk", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell


    cell?.baslik.text = fizik.baslik




    return cell!

}
```

I want to do the alphabetical order in  cell? .baslik.text = fizik.baslik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `fizik` declaration in `cellForItem` to this:

```
let fizik = self.fizikListe.sorted(by: { $0.baslik ?? "" < $1.baslik ?? ""})[indexPath.row]
```